# Setting Module Exports to Variable or Not and to Function or Not

Tags: node.js

What's the point in setting module.exports to a var vs. just exposing it as plain module.exports?  Here are 2 ways possible to set it to a variable and then last just setting it to plain old module.exports.  I'm trying to understand the use cases for doing it the various ways and also if the first example makes any sense to set it to an object when I'm doing that sort of thing already in my last example.

```
var board = module.exports = {
     doSomething: doSomething()
};

board.initialize = function(){
...
}
doSomethingElse = function(){
}
```

**or**

```
var board = module.exports = function(){
    initialize();
}

function initialize(){
...
}
board.doSomethingElse(){

}
```

or

```
module.exports = {
      doSomething: doSomething()
};

function doSomething(){
...
};
```

Seems like there are many ways to do the same kind of things but trying to make sense of good patterns and when.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between the first way and second way is that in the first you are exporting an object whereas in the second you're exporting a function. I generally export as a function if I need to inject some dependency into whatever I'm working with.

As for whether or not to assign module.exports to a variable, there is no practical difference between doing it and not doing it. I generally don't as I like to keep it at the bottom of my module as to highlight exactly what is being exported, but you can do it either way. The important thing is to just do it the same way throughout your application.